# How to write a select query with case to generate this output in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to generate a report like below.Here we are comparing COLUMN_A and COLUMN_B based on some conditions.

```
COLUMN_A      COLUMN_B    STATUS
100                        OK
250           350          NOT OK
300           NULL         NULL COLUMN_A
NULL          400          NULL COLUMN_B
```

- If the values in column_a and column_b are equal to each other i want to display only column_a value
  and nothing in column_b and another dummy column called status showing result as OK(Shown in first row)
- If the values in column_a and column_b are not equal to each other i want to display both column_a and column_b values and another dummy column called status showing result as NOT OK(Shown in second row)
- If the column_b value is null i want to display COLUMN_A value and NULL in COLUMN_B and status as NULL COLUMN_A (Shown in third row)

It is really confusing me. Is this even possible to get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select column_a,
       (case when column_a = column_b or column_b is null then null else column_b end) as column_b,
       (case when column_a = column_b then 'OK'
             when column_b is null then 'NULL ' || column_a
             when column_a is null then 'NULL' || column_b
             else 'NOT OK'
        end) as status
from . . .
```

Comment: You are a life saver. Thanks a lot. +1 from my side.

Comment: @user2647888 - if this solved your problem you should accept the answer